# Django Rest Framework. How can I serialize model name and instance values instead of content_type and object_id?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I believe there should be a straightforward way to do this, but I can't figure it out. Appreciate some help.

In a model like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.content_type) + str(self.content_object)
```

I serialized it like that:

```
class CaseDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Which returns me:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "object_id": 35,
        "content_type": 29
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "object_id": 36,
        "content_type": 31
    }
]
```

And I would like to have something like that:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "object_id": "A value from the instance such as name, instead of the ID",
        "content_type": "The name of the model, or even better, the verbose name"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "object_id": "A value from the instance such as name, instead of the ID",
        "content_type": "The name of the model, or even better, the verbose name"
    }
]
```

SlugRelatedField seems to be the way forward, but I can make it work.

Adding this to the serializer is a good stepforward.

```
content_type = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=ContentType.objects.all(),
        slug_field='model')
```

However, for the object_id is not so clear to me how to query since the model is not always the same.

Thanks in advance,
Felipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that information from attribute `content_object`, but you have to define two more fields on the serializer:

```
class CaseDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    model = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('content_type', 'object_id', 'name', 'model')

    def get_name(self, instance):
        try:
            return instance.content_object.name
        except:
            return None

    def get_model(self, instance):
        try:
            return instance.content_object.__class__.__name__
        except:
            return None
```

Comment: This is perfect. Works perfectly. I will dig into MethodSerializer. Many thanks.
get_model is missing a : in the end. Please correct if possible. Best regards.